# How would I return values in an array that are not in between a lower and upper threshold?

Tags: python, arrays

I've figured out how to return the values of an array that fall between a threshold, but I can't seem to figure out how to find the values that fall outside the threshold. From what I understand.. my code makes sense..

I've defined variables and said that if any value in my array is less than the lower value and higher than the upper value.. return the array with those values.

```
 import numpy as np
 def not_in_between(arg1,arg2,arg3): ## defined my array, low 
                                 ##  value, and upper value
     array1 = np.array(arg1)
     lower = np.array(arg2)
     upper = np.array(arg3)
     not_between = array1[((array1 < lower) & (array1 > upper))]
     return not_between
```

So if you have an array that is [1,2,3,4] and your lower value is 1 and the upper value is 3..
I expect the output to be 4.

Comment: i don't need someone to write any code I just need some clarification on why this would not work

Comment: I think you meant or `|` instead of an and `&`?

Comment: ahhh @DanielMesejo I think that all makes sense now thank you

Comment: I find that it helps using "and" instead of "&" also "or" instead of "|". makes it clearer what im actually doing

Answer (score 0):

```
def not_in_between(arg1,lower,upper): ## defined my array, low
                                 ##  value, and upper value
    not_between = [x for x in arg1 if x not in range(lower,upper+1)]
    return not_between
print(not_in_between([1,2,3,4],1,3))
```

Try this hopefully it will work as expected.